# Cannot find module 'babel-plugin-react-native-dotenv'

Tags: react-native, expo

This is the error that am getting when i tried to run my code in Expo.
`App.js: Cannot find module 'babel-plugin-babel-preset-expo`

Any solution would be appreciated.
My babel.config.js looks like this

````
module.exports = function(api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    plugins: ['babel-preset-expo','module:react-native-dotenv'],
  }
}```

https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/10964
Well this guy had similar error.I don;t think it has been resolved i guess.
````

Answer (score 4):

Your babel configuration looks wrong.

replace your `babel.config.js` file with

```js
module.exports = function (api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: ['babel-preset-expo'],
    plugins: [
      ["module:react-native-dotenv", {
        "moduleName": "@env"
      }]
    ]
  };
};
```

Now you can import your environment variables by

```js
import { ENV_VARIABLE_NAME } from "@env"
```

where `ENV_VARIABLE_NAME` is the name you specified in your `.env` file

Comment: This is the error that i got when i replaced babel file. `App.js: [BABEL] D:\react\weatho\weatho-app\App.js: .plugins is not a valid Plugin property`import `{REACT_APP_WEATHER_API_KEY} from "react-native-dotenv";` is the line i have i used in App.js file and my env file contains `REACT_APP_WEATHER_API_KEY=2607fb610e6f9fecd16c84408d0b42a2`

Comment: can I see your babel.cofig file?

Comment: I even tried to replace `{REACT_APP_WEATHER_API_KEY} from "react-native-dotenv` with '@env' as you have told.But I still get same error

Comment: `module.exports = function (api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: ['babel-preset-expo'],
    plugins: [
      ["module:react-native-dotenv", {
        "moduleName": "@env"
      }]
    ]
  };
};`.This is my babel.config file.I just replaced with the code you gave in the previous post